# What's wrong with this PHP CURL script (integrating Foursquare API)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, foursquare

I am trying to integrate [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/photos/add) to my website, here is the code:

```
$curl = curl_init('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?v=20181008&oauth_token='.$token.'&photo='.$args['img'].'&venueId='.$title);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// Decode the response
$data = json_decode($data);

// Verify if the post was published
if ( @$data->meta->code == 200) {
        return true;
} else {
        return false;
}
```

But when I run this script on my website and try to post image, it is showing

> An error occurred while processing your request

Comment: First thing I see is that they want you to set the "Content-Type" to "image/jpeg". You have "multipart/form-data". And you should check, if your picture is bigger than 5mb since they say it can't be bigger.

Comment: @LLJ97 the picture is not bigger than 5 mb and I tried with Content-Type as image/jpeg but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lines

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));
```

and try a simple

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

You are sending the Request with GET Arguments

Comment: actually that is a post request

Comment: Another possibility: By creating the Url, are there any characters, that have to be url_encoded?

Comment: And you don't add the data to your Request Body. Try curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args['img']); But send the content of $args['img']

Comment: $curl = curl_init(urlencode('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add?v=20181008&oauth_token='.$token.'&photo='.$args['img'].'&venueId='.$title));

Comment: I don't get you...send the contents mean?

Comment: I think $args['img'] is a file on your Disk? Send the content of this $file. For example curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, file_get_contents ($args['img']));

Answer (score 0):

This could have multiple reasons.
I can't tell from the error message where exactly it triggers but when the curl fails, you should first investigate if there were any issues with the curl request itself.

Use curl_error  for this: http://php.net/manual/de/function.curl-error.php

And are you using the API-Call the correct way?
In the docs POST https://api.foursquare.com/v2/photos/add
theres no `$photo` param at all.

Also when using `POST` you should add the parameters via

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);`

and not as GET-Parameters via URL.